# Stepping into python code (keras) with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, visual-studio-debugging

I'm trying to see if the keras-tcn code (https://github.com/philipperemy/keras-tcn) can be used with tensorflow.keras in place of keras. I've made the usual keras -> tensorflow.keras substitutions. I get an error in the code below at the Convolution1D ctor:

```
def __call__(self, inputs):
        if self.dilations is None:
            self.dilations = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
        x = inputs
        x = Convolution1D(self.nb_filters, 1, padding=self.padding, name=self.name + '_initial_conv')(x)
```

ValueError: Attr 'padding' of 'Conv2D' Op passed string 'CAUSAL' not in: "SAME", "VALID".

I can see by examining the source code that 'causal' is indeed supported in this version of tf (1.10.0). So to try and understand what's happening I set a breakpoint and then try to step into the ctor, but the debugger just steps over and throws an exception. I also set a breakpoint in the underlying code, op_def_library.py, but it never gets hit.

I set the VS option: **Tools|Options|Python|Debugging|Enable debugging of the Python standard library**, but this made no difference.

Is this possible, or should I be using a different debugger if I want to step into third-party modules?

Comment: In the error, it is mentioned as Con2D whereas in your code you are using Convolution1D

Comment: Good catch Shubham. The code I'm running is the adding_problem task from the keras-tcn repository. Conv2D is not used anywhere in this code. This problem does not occur if run with keras in place of tensorflow.keras.